# Show portfolio category slug in url ( if exist)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm trying to achieve a two level portfolio structure, and it works fine in the breadcrumbs but not in the URL. The idea is to show the portfolio slug (destinations) followed by the portfolio category (if exist) and last the portfolio name.
This is the file (portfolio-post.php) that needs to be altered, but i have no clue on how to do that, any help would be appreciated:

```
<?php

   /*******************************************************************************************************************
 * Create and register Portfolio post type
 */
if ( !function_exists('ishyoboy_portfolio_post_type') ){
function ishyoboy_portfolio_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => __( 'Portfolio', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'Portfolio Item', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'add_new'           => _x( 'Add New Item', 'portfolio-post', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Item', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Portfolio Item', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'new_item'          => __( 'New Portfolio Item', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'view_item'         => __( 'View Portfolio Item', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Portfolio Items', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'not_found'         => __( 'No Portfolio Items Found', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'=> __( 'No Portfolio Items Found In Trash', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Portfolio Item', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Portfolio', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Portfolio Items', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
    );
    $taxonomies = array();
    $supports = apply_filters( 'ish_cpt_plugin_portfolio_post_type_supports', array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ) );

    global $ish_options;

    if ( isset( $ish_options['slug_portfolio'] ) && '' != $ish_options['slug_portfolio'] ){
        $slug = trim( $ish_options['slug_portfolio'] );
    } else {
        $slug = _x('portfolio', 'URL slug', 'ishyoboy_assets'); // "URL slug" is necessary for WPML to be able to translate the slug
    }

    $post_type_args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'singular_label'        => __( 'Portfolio' , 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'rewrite'               => array(
            'slug'              => $slug,
            'with_front'        => true,
            'feed'              => true,
            'pages'             => false
        ),
        'supports'              => $supports,
        'menu_position'         => null,
        'menu_icon'             => null, //get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/slider/images/icon.png',
        'taxonomies'            => $taxonomies
    );

    register_post_type( 'portfolio-post', $post_type_args );

}
}


/*******************************************************************************************************************
 * Set Portfolio post type's messages
 */
if ( !function_exists('ishyoboy_portfolio_messages') ){
function ishyoboy_portfolio_messages($messages)
{
    global $post, $post_ID;

    $messages['portfolio-post'] =
        array(
            0 => '',
            1 => sprintf(('Portfolio Updated. <a href="%s">View portfolio</a>'), esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
            2 => __('Custom Field Updated.', 'ishyoboy_assets'),
            3 => __('Custom Field Deleted.', 'ishyoboy_assets'),
            4 => __('Portfolio Updated.', 'ishyoboy_assets'),
            5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Portfolio Restored To Revision From %s', 'ishyoboy_assets'), wp_post_revision_title((int)$_GET['revision'], false)) : false,
            6 => sprintf(__('Portfolio Published. <a href="%s">View Portfolio</a>', 'ishyoboy_assets'), esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
            7 => __('Portfolio Saved.', 'ishyoboy_assets'),
            8 => sprintf(__('Portfolio Submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview Portfolio</a>', 'ishyoboy_assets'), esc_url( add_query_arg('preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID)))),
            9 => sprintf(__('Portfolio Scheduled For: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview Portfolio</a>', 'ishyoboy_assets'), date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i', 'ishyoboy_assets' ), strtotime($post->post_date)), esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
            10 => sprintf(__('Portfolio Draft Updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview Portfolio</a>', 'ishyoboy_assets'), esc_url( add_query_arg('preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID)))),
        );
    return $messages;
}
}
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'ishyoboy_portfolio_messages' );


/*******************************************************************************************************************
 * Create Category for Portfolio post type
*/
if ( !function_exists('ishyoboy_portfolio_category') ){
function ishyoboy_portfolio_category()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name'                          => __( 'Portfolio Categories', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'singular_name'                 => __( 'Portfolio Category', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'search_items'                  => __( 'Search Portfolio Categories', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'popular_items'                 => __( 'Popular Portfolio Categories', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'all_items'                     => __( 'All Portfolio Categories', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'parent_item'                   => __( 'Parent Portfolio Category', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'edit_item'                     => __( 'Edit Portfolio Category', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'update_item'                   => __( 'Update Portfolio Category', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'add_new_item'                  => __( 'Add New Portfolio Category', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'new_item_name'                 => __( 'New Portfolio Category', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas'    => __( 'Separate Portfolio Categories with commas', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'           => __( 'Add or remove Portfolio Category', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'         => __( 'Choose from most used Portfolio Categories', 'ishyoboy_assets' )
    );

    global $ish_options;
    if ( isset( $ish_options['slug_portfolio'] ) && '' != $ish_options['slug_portfolio'] ){
        $slug = trim( $ish_options['slug_portfolio'] ) . '-category';
    } else {
        $slug = _x('portfolio-category', 'URL slug', 'ishyoboy_assets'); // "URL slug" is necessary for WPML to be able to translate the slug
    }

    $args = array(
        'labels'                        => $labels,
        'public'                        => true,
        'hierarchical'                  => true,
        'show_ui'                       => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'             => true,
        'query_var'                     => true,
        "rewrite"                       => array(
            'slug'          => $slug,
            'hierarchical'  => true
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-category', 'portfolio-post', $args );
}
}

if ( is_admin() ){

       /*******************************************************************************************************************
 * Backend columns
 */
if ( !function_exists('ishyoboy_portfolio_edit_columns') ){
    function ishyoboy_portfolio_edit_columns( $columns ){
        $columns = array(
            "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
            "title" => __( 'Title', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
            "author" => __( 'Author', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
            "category" => __( 'Categories', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
            "thumbnail" => __( 'Image', 'ishyoboy_assets' ),
            "date" => __( 'Date', 'ishyoboy_assets' )
        );

        return $columns;
    }
}
add_filter("manage_edit-portfolio-post_columns", "ishyoboy_portfolio_edit_columns");


if ( !function_exists('ishyoboy_portfolio_custom_columns') ){
    function ishyoboy_portfolio_custom_columns($column){
        global $post;

        switch ($column)
        {
            case "thumbnail":
                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                break;
            case "category":
                echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'portfolio-category', '', ', ','');
                break;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_portfolio-post_posts_custom_column' ,    'ishyoboy_portfolio_custom_columns', 10, 2 );

    /**
 * Add dropdown filter for sliders
 */

    if ( !function_exists('ishyoboy_restrict_portfolio_by_category') ){
    function ishyoboy_restrict_portfolio_by_category() {
        global $typenow, $wp_query;

        if ( isset($typenow) && 'portfolio-post' == $typenow ) {

            $taxonomy = 'portfolio-category';

            $term = isset( $wp_query->query[$taxonomy]) ? $wp_query->query[$taxonomy] : '';

            $portfolio_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
            wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                'show_option_all' =>  __("Show all", 'ishyoboy_assets') . ' ' . $portfolio_taxonomy->label,
                'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy,
                'name'            =>  $taxonomy,
                'orderby'         =>  'name',
                'selected'        =>  $term,
                'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                'depth'           =>  0,
                'show_count'      =>  true, // Show # listings in parens
                'hide_empty'      =>  true, // Don't show businesses w/o listings
            ));
        }
    }
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts','ishyoboy_restrict_portfolio_by_category');

if ( !function_exists('taxonomy_filter_ishyoboy_portfolio_request') ){
    function taxonomy_filter_ishyoboy_portfolio_request( $query ) {
        global $pagenow, $typenow;

        if ( isset($pagenow) && 'edit.php' == $pagenow ) {

            $filters = get_object_taxonomies( $typenow );
            if ( isset($filters) && '' != $filters){
                foreach ( $filters as $tax_slug ) {
                    $var = &$query->query_vars[$tax_slug];
                    if ( isset($var) && '' != $var ) {
                        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $var, $tax_slug );
                        if ( isset($term) && '' !=  $term ) {
                            $var = $term->slug;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'taxonomy_filter_ishyoboy_portfolio_request' );


if ( !function_exists('ishyoboy_portfolio_post_thumbnails') ){
    function ishyoboy_portfolio_post_thumbnails() {

        $supported_types = get_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        if ( $supported_types === false ) {
            add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'portfolio-post' ) );
        }
        elseif( true === $supported_types){

        }
        elseif( is_array( $supported_types[0] ) ){
            $supported_types[0][] = 'portfolio-post';
            add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', $supported_types[0] );
        }

    }
    }


/**
 * Change the default setting for comments on Portfolio posts. Make them closed by default.
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'ishyoboy_default_content_portfolio' ) ) {
    function ishyoboy_default_content_portfolio( $post_content, $post ) {
        if( $post->post_type )
            switch( $post->post_type ) {
                case 'portfolio-post':
                    $post->comment_status = 'closed';
                    break;
            }
        return $post_content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'default_content', 'ishyoboy_default_content_portfolio', 10, 2 );

}

   /*******************************************************************************************************************
 * Initialize Portfolio post type
 */
add_action( 'init', 'ishyoboy_portfolio_post_type' );
add_action( 'init', 'ishyoboy_portfolio_category', 0 );
//add_action( 'after_theme_setup','ishyoboy_portfolio_post_thumbnails' );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the portfolio category in the url you could possibly navigate to Settings > Permalinks and add a custom structure like so %category%/%postname% that will add the category before the postname.

Comment: Thanks for your help. have to say that i've tried it already. but with no luck i'm afraid.also tried a plugin called 'Custom Post Type Permalinks', but it did not help as well